# How to convert a file with extended attributes to AppleDouble format?

Tags: terminal, extended-attributes

How can I convert a file, which has extended attributes, to [AppleDouble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleSingle_and_AppleDouble_formats) format? I know how to convert *from* AppleDouble format using the Terminal utility [`dot_clean`](https://maclovin.org/blog-native/2017/dotclean-merge-files-with-corresponding-native-files), but what utility can be used to convert *to* AppleDouble format?

Comment: My apologies, I have the feeling the answer to this question should be just a search query away, but my google-fu seems to be failing me at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven’t found a utility that’s specifically intended to convert to AppleDouble format, but I realized `ditto` and `unzip` can be (ab)used to do this: `ditto` will convert to AppleDouble format when adding a file to a zip archive. Extracting the archive using `ditto` converts it back, but this is not the case when using the regular `unzip` command which retains the two files in AppleDouble format. Thus, one can do:

```
$ ditto -c -k file.txt archive.zip; unzip -o archive.zip
Archive:  archive.zip
  inflating: file.txt              
  inflating: ._file.txt
```

There must be a better way to do this, but I haven’t come across it yet.